# Solve discrete Algebratic Riccati Equation if S is non-square - How?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter

I have the state-space model

$$\dot x = Ax + Bu + W$$
$$y = Cx + Du + E$$

where $E\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (N-1)}$ is a noise vector and $W\in \mathbb{R}^{p \times (N-1)}$ a disturbance vector.

What I need to do is to find the covariance matrix of $W$ and $E$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{ww} & \Sigma_{we} \\ 
\Sigma_{ew} & \Sigma_{ee} 
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{N-1}\begin{bmatrix}
WW^T & WE^T \\ 
EW^T & EE^T
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Assume that we calling they for these matrices instead.

$$ S = \Sigma_{we} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$$
$$ Q = \Sigma_{ww} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$
$$ R = \Sigma_{ee} \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$$

**Question:**

If I want to solve the discrete algebraic Riccati equation for computing the Kalman gain matrix.

$$X = \tilde A^TX\tilde A - E^TXE - (\tilde A^TX\tilde B + S)(\tilde B^TX\tilde B + R)^{-1}(\tilde A^TX\tilde B + S)^T + Q$$

Where $E = 0, \tilde B = C^T, \tilde A = A^T$

But here is the problem. $X$ is a square matrix of the size $n \times n$ and this part $(\tilde A^TX\tilde B + S)^T$ result a matrix of the size $p \times n$ where $(\tilde B^TX\tilde B + R)^{-1}$ have the size $n \times n$. $\tilde (A^TX\tilde B + S)$ have the size $n\times p$. They cannot be multiplied...because $S$ is not square as $A$ is.

So how can I solve the algebraic Riccati equation if $S$ is not square?

**Update:**

Here is the source of the equations and formulas. It's from the book
**Subspace Methods for System Identification** by Tohru Katayama, ISBN-10: 1852339810

[image]

Comment: This is a very unclear question. How come $W,E$ can have $N-1$ columns while the state or the output are vectors? Also, your definition of the covariance matrix is strange, please check that. There are dimension problems in your discussion below the Riccati equation. Please go through your post and provide more details together with some corrections.

Comment: @KBS Thank you for your response. I just followed a book called Subspace Identification Methods. The definition of covariance matrix is strange, yes I know. But the formula says it must be like this.

Comment: Also, in a covariance matrix, $S$ is not square in general. So, there is a confusion here somewhere.

Comment: As usual, when you use a resource, you need to mention it, with a proper mention of the page where the result is.

Comment: @KBS Can I post a print screen?  (cropped)

Comment: You can, but it is better to post a complete reference so people can have a look at it. It is often the case that all the needed information is not on the picture.

Comment: @KBS Yes. I understand.

Comment: I have checked the book and your post is very unclear. You did not mention all the important details regarding the system, where the state vector is not a vector. In this regard, all the context is missing. It is important that you ask clear and complete questions in the future. In any way, there is no problem with the Riccati equation. The term $(\tilde A^TX\tilde B + S)$ is of dimension $n\times p$, $\tilde B^TX\tilde B + R$ of dimension $p\times p$, and not $n\times n$.

Comment: @KBS I see the problem now. I assumed that $R$ is a $nxn$ matrix, but it must be a $pxp$ matrix!

Comment: Are you considering the Kalman filter in continuous or discrete time? Namely, your initial state space model suggests continues time, while the Riccati equation is for discrete time.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes, it's discrete time only. I have build a subspace identification with the CCA method. Very robust against noise. Have you been into system identification before? Such as subspace identification and the realization theory?